# Transform data frame into matrix: two columns as row and column names

Tags: r, graph, matrix

In R I have data structured like this:

```
Ref  Url   Moves
1    1     345
1    2     765
1    3     923
1    4     233
2    1     6
2    2     23
2    3     345
2    4     354
3    1     954
...
```

I would like to convert it to a matrix and then plot it as a graph with number of moves represented by line width.
What I need is to reshape the data into something like:

```
    1    2    3 ...
1   345  765  923
2   6    23   345
3   954  ...  ...
...
```

Does anybody have an idea how to do that automatically in R? It would be great if it could work not only with numbers in first and second column but also with strings, so that I could have a matrix with this strings as row and column names.

Cheers,
P

Comment: @James That one should be an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using acast is one way to go. But I like James's way

```
library(reshape2)
dd <- read.table(header = T, textConnection("Ref  Url   Moves
 1    1     345
 1    2     765
 1    3     923
 1    4     233
 2    1     6
 2    2     23
 2    3     345
 2    4     354
 3    1     954"))

acast(dd, Ref ~ Url)
Using Moves as value column: use value_var to override.
    1   2   3   4
1 345 765 923 233
2   6  23 345 354
3 954  NA  NA  NA
```

HTH

Answer (score 7):

Using the data provided by Iselzer, you can use `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(Moves~Ref+Url,dd)
   Url
Ref   1   2   3   4
  1 345 765 923 233
  2   6  23 345 354
  3 954   0   0   0
```